# making a regex that allows all email characters except from the @ symbol

Tags: php, regex, laravel

Hi so I've been trying to work around this very basic thing which is to allow email accepted characters but not allow the @ sign, because I am forcing the domain part of an email via a dropdown box which the user selects, therefore there should be no @ sign in the email input.

I had this regular expression that included the @ after the first class however removing it doesn't seem to allow any characters at all.

```
^([a-z0-9_\.-])+([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$
```

Anyone able to point me in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex seems to work quite well for example for this string: `nameDomain.com`

See it here https://regex101.com/r/pAtPIg/1 in action.

However, the regex is not shellproof... For example it will match this string `nameDomain...`, too, wich is not a vaild email (stripped by `@` sign)...

Comment: Thats exactly what I've just realised. Basically my drop box does the domain part e.g. @domain.net  so I need it to somehow avoid people from entering domains in the regex

Comment: nvm ive reverted back to not using a dropdown box. - Fixed.